# Can a Homogeneous Differential Equation be Nonlinear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, definition

First of all, I am not asking about $v=y/x$ transformation kinda homogeneous.

Can we say  this nonlinear differential equation is homogeneous $$y^{\prime}=ty^2.$$

Here there is no term without $y$, this is okay. But this is nonlinear equation.

I saw here some discussions and some people said it is just for linear equations. I want to give two links:

[Dummies Series](http://www.dummies.com/education/math/trigonometry/defining-homogeneous-and-nonhomogeneous-differential-equations/) (assumes it can be nonlinear) (I also see some universities documents too).

[Wolfram Math World](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html) (assumes it has to be linear)

Which one is the definition:

1) No term without $y$,

2) Linear and No term without $y$.

3) $y$ is a solution, then $\lambda y$ is solution for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

**Considering the references, I will use the 3rd one.** This option is also meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the title-question is: Yes, it can. Here are two references.

> The paper *[On the second order homogeneous quadratic differential equation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01367452)* by Roger Chalkley considers **homogeneous quadratic** differential equations of the form
>   \begin{align*}
> Q(y)\equiv a\left(y^{\prime\prime}\right)^2+by^{\prime\prime}y^{\prime}+cy^{\prime\prime}y+d\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2
> +ey^\prime y+fy^2=0\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> from which we conclude *[linearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity)* and *[homogeneity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html)* are two  concepts which *do not* exclude each other.

*Note:* The Math world page does not include the term *linear* in the definition of *Homogeneous Ordinary Differential Equation*. It rather uses a linear differential equation as an easy to follow example for a *homogeneous ordinary differential equation*.

> Another example is the paper
>
> *[Classification and Analysis of Two-Dimensional Real](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022039679900378)* **Homogeneous Quadratic** *Differential Equation Systems* by Tsutomu Date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In order to make it clear: (I am understanding like that) Homogeneous differential equation means that after rewriting the (any) differential equation in the form $Q(y)=0$, then if $Q(\lambda y)=\lambda^r Q(y)$ for some real number $r$, we will call the equation as homogeneous.

Comment: @studentforever: Yes, *homogeneous* means if $y$ fits $Q(y)$ then so does $\lambda y$ for any constant $\lambda$. If the right side were a nonzero function then $\lambda y$ would no longer be a solution and  is then called *inhomogeneous*.

Comment: By the way, the link you give about homogeneity gives the equation in the form of linear ODE.

Comment: @studentforever: As indicated in the note, I don't think this is essential with respect to the definition of *homogeneity*.

Comment: @studentforever: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! :-)

Comment: I am actually grateful. The knowledge is priceless. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is to some extent a matter of convention and as with many things different conventions exist.

Consider the following related notion: a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is called *homogeneous* of degree $\alpha$, if $f(kx) = k^\alpha f(x)$. We could apply this to ODEs and say that an ODE 
$$
y'(t) = f(t, y(t))
$$
is homogeneous, if the right hand side is homogeneous in the $y$-variable. With this definition your example would be homogeneous of degree 2.

I would not call the ODE
$$ y'''' + ty'' + y^2 = 0$$
in the first example you linked homogeneous. Informally, the term *homogeneous* implies that we have some form of scaling behaviour.

I have come across homogeneous ODEs only in the context of linear equations, but it is possible that more general notions exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually think similar. But I don't call  first one homogenous of degree two. Left hand side is degree one and right hand side is degree two. I shall call $(y^{\prime\prime})^2=yy^\prime$ is homegenous of degree $2$ . Here if $y$ is solution, then $\lambda y$ is solution. Even solution space is not a vector space, it has this nice property.