# First order non-linear ordinary differential equation containing $e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(t+e^y) + \left(\frac{t^2}{2} + 2te^y\right)y' = 0$$

How can i solve this? I've never seen a differential equation like that.

Answer (score 2):

$$(t+e^y)+\left(\dfrac{t^2}2+2te^y\right)\dfrac{dy}{dt}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow 2(t+e^y)dt+(t^2+4te^y)dy=0$$

$$2tdt+2e^ydt+t^2dy+4te^ydy=0$$
$$$$
On multiplying throughout by $e^y$ (to convert the ODE into an exact ODE) and subsequently rearranging, we get 
$$$$
$$(2te^ydt+t^2e^ydy)+ 2(2te^{2y}dy+e^{2y}dt)=0$$ 
$$d(t^2e^y)+d(2e^{2y}t)=0$$
$$t^2e^y+2te^{2y}=C$$
$$$$
Edit: If you (like me) dislike messy looking terms, you can substitute $u=e^y$ in the first step and modify the equation.

Comment: @KHH Kindly consider upvoting and accepting the answers to your questions on this site if the answers help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is an [inexact ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inexact_differential_equation). Let's write it as
$$
(t+ \exp y)dt + \left(\frac{t^2}{2} + 2t \exp y \right) dy = M(t,y) dt + N(t,y) dy = 0.
$$
It is an inexact differential form, because there is no function $F(t,y)$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = M, \ \ \ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = N,
$$
which is bad, since, if there was such $F$, we could solve the ODE readly. Fortunatelly, if we multiply our ODE by any function $\mu(t,y)$, nothing happens, since the LHS is zero (thanks *Dylan* for the comment on the homogeneity). The details are in the provided Wikipedia link, but if 
$$
\frac{1}{M} \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial t}\right) = f(y) \ \mathrm{or} \ \frac{1}{N} \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial t}\right) = f(t),
$$
pleasant things happen, because the new ODE
$$
\mu M(t,y) dt + \mu N(t,y) dy = 0
$$
becames a exact differential form! If you perform the calculations, you will se that 
$$
\frac{1}{M} \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial t}\right) = -1,
$$
which is a function of $y$, anyway. Then, taking $\mu = \exp \int -f(y) dy = \exp y$, our new ODE is
$$
\exp y(t+ \exp y)dt + \exp y\left(\frac{t^2}{2} + 2t \exp y \right) dy =0.
$$
Since it is now a exact differential form, we can readly integrate this way:
$$
\int \exp y(t+ \exp y)dt + \int \exp y\left(\frac{t^2}{2} + 2t \exp y \right) dy = c.
$$
$$
\exp y \left(\frac{t^2}{2}+ t \exp y \right) + \left(\frac{t^2}{2} \exp y + t \exp 2y \right) = c.
$$
Simplifying:
$$
2t \exp 2y + t^2 \exp y = c,
$$
which you can see as a quadractic equation of $\exp y$:
$$
2t (\exp y)^2 + t^2 \exp y - c = 0,
$$
using the quadractic formula:
$$
\exp y = \frac{-t^2 \pm \sqrt{t^4 + 8ct}}{4t}
$$
solving for $y$:
$$
y = \log \frac{-t^2 \pm \sqrt{t^4 + 8ct}}{4t}.
$$

PS.: See that the solution is non-unique, i.e., there are two solutions, corresponding to the $+$ and $-$ sign. If you write your equation in the standard form,
$$
y' = - \frac{t+ \exp y}{\frac{t^2}{2} + 2t \exp y} = F(t,y),
$$
you can see that $F(t,y)$ is not [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity), i.e., the [derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdy%20-(t%2Bexp(y))%2F(t%5E2%2F2%2B2t%20exp%20y)) of $F(t,y)$ in relation to $y$ gets unbounded for certain values of $t$. Therefore, [the Picard-Lindenlöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) can not ensure the uniqueness of the solution (nor the existence, but we constructed a solution for it).

Comment: The RHS being zero does not always mean the equation is homogeneous. That only applies to linear equations.

Comment: @Dylan I see... but can you please provide a counterexample? I can't imagine one...

Comment: This equation right here is not homogeneous. Remember, a homogeneous function requires $f(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \lambda^k f(x,y)$.

Comment: @Dylan I see what you mean. However, I was referring to 'homogeneous' in the sense of an equation whose RHS is zero when written in the standard form, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients).

Comment: [A linear differential equation  is homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_linear_differential_equations) if, for any solution $y(x)$, $\lambda y(x)$ is also a solution. This is satisfied if every non-zero term is dependent on $y^{(k)}(x)$. Hence, a RHS of zero is a *property* of a homogeneous equation, not a *definition*

Comment: @Dylan Take a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html) to see the two meanings of the expression _homogeneous differential equation_.

Comment: We're just arguing semantics at this point. All I was trying to say is, the equation in this question is *not* homogeneous, and that has been agreed upon.

Comment: @Dylan I'm afraid we had not agreed in this point. The pointed equation _is_ homogeneous according to the first meaning in the MathWorld page, but _is not_ homogeneous according to the second meaning.

Comment: ...This equation isn't linear, so the first definition fails to apply.

Comment: @Dylan take a look here then: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2181392/493334

Comment: You provided a link that mentions second-order quadratic equations, which this one isn't. No definitions are provided, either. I'm not convinced.

Comment: @Dylan I have no more evidence to show. I, particularly, think there is no problem to use the expression _homogeneous_ in this context. Anyway, as you can see in the edit on the answer, the ambiguous or possibly imprecise expression _homogeneous_ was eliminated. Furthermore, thanks for this interesting discussion!

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. To be fair, I never intended for the comment chain to go this long.